# Using FsCheck to Generate Records

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'd like to use FsCheck (with XUnit) to create records of type: `type QueryRequest = {Symbol: string; StartDate: DateTime; EndDate: DateTime}` where `Symbol` is limited to 3 options - `ORCL`, `IBM`, `AAPL`, and `StartDate` and `EndDate` are limited to the range between **January 1, 2000** and **January 1, 2019**.

However, I'm unclear as to how proceed. Should I use `Arb.generate<T>` or `Arb.Default` or some other utility upon which to base the generation and shrinking of the test cases?

---

**Update 1**

Follow-on question related to issues generating records is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635256/issues-creating-records-with-fscheck).

> ```
> Original:
> { Symbol = ""
>   StartDate = 8/9/2057 4:07:10 AM
>   EndDate = 10/14/2013 6:15:32 PM }
> Shrunk:
> { Symbol = ""
>   StartDate = 8/9/2057 12:00:00 AM
>   EndDate = 10/14/2013 12:00:00 AM }
> ```

---

**Update 2**

Following is test suite code:

```
namespace Parser

open Xunit
open FsCheck.Xunit
open DataGenerators

module Tests =
    [<Fact>]
    let ``sanity check`` () =
        let expected = true
        let actual = true
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual)

    [<Property(Arbitrary = [|typeof<StockTwitGenerator>|])>]
    let ``validate queries`` (q: QueryRecord) =
        q.EndDate > q.StartDate
```

Comment: `it doesn’t quite work` is not a good problem description. I’d remove your update and ask a separate question.

Comment: @CaringDev agreed; separated follow-on question. Link to follow-on provided in original post update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have constraints that limit the values to a small subset of all allowed values for a given type, constructing a valid value is easier and more safe<sup>1</sup> than filtering.

Given...

```
open FsCheck
open System

type QueryRequest = {Symbol: string; StartDate: DateTime; EndDate: DateTime}
```

... we can start by creating a generator for Symbols:

```
let symbols = ["ORCL"; "IBM"; "AAPL"]
let symbol = Gen.elements symbols
```

and a date range

```
let minDate = DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
let maxDate = DateTime(2019, 1, 1)
let dateRange = maxDate - minDate
let date =
    Gen.choose (0, int dateRange.TotalDays)
    |> Gen.map (float >> minDate.AddDays)
```

Note that `Gen.choose` only accepts an `int` range. We can work around by generating a random offset of at max the allowed date difference and then mapping back to a `DateTime`

Using those, we can construct a generator for `QueryRequest`s...

```
let query =
    gen {
        let! s = symbol
        let! d1 = date
        let! d2 = date
        let startDate, endDate = if d1 < d2 then d1, d2 else d2, d1 
        return { Symbol = s; StartDate = startDate; EndDate = endDate }
    }

type MyGenerators =
  static member QueryRequest() =
      {new Arbitrary<QueryRequest>() with
          override _.Generator = query }
```

... register ...

```
Arb.register<MyGenerators>()
```

and finally test:

```
let test { Symbol = s; StartDate = startDate; EndDate = endDate } =
    symbols |> Seq.contains s && startDate >= minDate && endDate <= maxDate && startDate <= endDate

Check.Quick test
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
FsCheck Documentation

> Make sure there is a high chance that the predicate is satisfied.

Comment: How did you know that `gen` would accept a computation expression?

Comment: Thanks, in original read through I skipped down to examples. For others' future reference the explanation re: computation expressions starts in paragraph two of the provided link.

Comment: When executing test cases with the generator you provided as an example above, the cases include erroneous/malformed records (see update in post for examples) that have missing symbols, and end dates that precede start dates. Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: How are you executing the tests? Are you sure you registered the generators? When I execute the above, even for 10s of 1000s of executions, I don't get wrong data...

Comment: I updated code to include test suite. Essentially, I was executing `dotnet test` with the expectation that it would run all identified tests. This happened as expected, but apparently the issue was a default arbitrary instance was used rather than the custom "StockTwitGenerator". To resolve this issue, I specified the arbitrary value in the property attribute (see update 2). I had to specify this value irrespective of whether I registered generator i.e. `Arb.register<StockTwitGenerator>() |> ignore`.

Comment: To your knowledge is there a way to configure FsCheck to use the custom arbitrary as a primary, aside from specifying it in a property attribute, with the default as a fallback?

Comment: You could use xUnit CollectionFixture or a constructor. I also tried with module initializers but failed :-/

Answer (score 3):

Arb.filter filters the generator and shrinker for a given Arbitrary instance to contain only those values that match with the given filter function. This should help you meet your needs.

https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html#Useful-methods-on-the-Arb-module
https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/ArbitraryExtensions.fs#L17-17